# Display images from protected folder

Tags: yii, imageview

I have a protected folder within Yii and I'm looking to display some of those images within the site. I've tried the following code and it works within the site/index controller in that it returns just the image I wanted.

However when I tried to separate the code it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

**Model**

```
    public function getImage() // will take file identifier as @param       
{

    $imageID = '2562584569'; // will eventually be dynamically assigned

    $image = Images::model()->find('tmp_name=:id', array('id' => $imageID)); 

    $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

    $file = $dest .'/' . $image->tmp_name . '.' . $image->extension;

    if(file_exists($file)){
    ob_clean();
    header('Content-Type:' . $image->logo_type);
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }

}
```

**And in the view**

```
CHtml::link('<img src="' . Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/images/image" />', array('product/index', 'id'=>$data['product_id'], 'slug'=> $data['product_slug']));
```

Thanks

Jonnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went about it like this

```
CHtml::link('<img src="' . $this->createUrl('/images/image', array('data'=>$data['data'])) . '" />', array('product/index', 'id'=>$data['product_id'], 'slug'=> $data['product_slug']));
```

**Model**

```
public function actionImage($data)       
{

$image = Images::model()->find('tmp_name=:data', array('id' => $data)); 

$dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

$file = $dest .'/' . $image->tmp_name . '.' . $image->extension;

if(file_exists($file)){
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type:' . $image->logo_type);
readfile($file);
exit;
}

}
```

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 2):

"protected" folder are not accessible from the client browser. This prevents people to have access to important files, like your source code.

If you want to store images inside "protected" and want them to be accessible, you need to publish them using `CAssetManager`.

Usage is something like:

```
$path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/path-inside-protected';
$yourImageUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($path);
```

Yii will then use the file as an asset, coping it to the "assets" folder, sibling to "protected". After that, you can just use the url returned on your HTML.

```
<img src="<?php echo $yourImageUrl ?>">
```

Comment: Ok, I'm retrieving a list of results, part of the result set is a product logo, so i've been using the `controller/method/id` as the src and passing it the `id` to the method. So images/image/2562584569 relates to image controller, getimage() method, file id. Still can't get the image to display though

Comment: The thing is.. You just cant view the images that are stored inside the protected folder, no matter whatever method that you try until you use the assetManager to copy those files in the asset directory.

The other method is to modify the .htaccess file if you are working in Apache. My guess is that you are. However, I would strongly advice against modifying it.

Comment: I was thinking of this general idea, not sure on implementation though. Basically the src tag calls a particular model/method/id, confirm the file exists, then get a proxy to return to access the file and return the image? Would that work?

Comment: havent tried that.. But my guess it .. it may work. Do tell me what your results are.