# how to properly display the image coming from an image folder of a module in Yii 1.x?

Tags: yii

i have to display a png file as a deleteButtonImageUrl. my problem now is, the image is inside an image directory of the current module. so the structure is like this

```
/application/
            modules/
                   /mymodule
                            /assets
                                   /img
                                       /admin
                                             /thePicture.png
                   /anotherModule
                   /anotherModule
```

how to get that image to display it ?
I already tried

```
deleteButtonImageUrl' => Yii::app()->basePath.'mymodule/assets/img/admin/thePicture.png',
```

doesn't work.

I also tried

```
'deleteButtonImageUrl' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('modules/mymodule/assets/image/admin/').'thePicture.png'
```

but still doesn't work. so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display images from protected folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889381/display-images-from-protected-folder)

Comment: +1 If you have properly set up application modules would not be accessible. Even if you provided proper link to image server would not allow you to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `Yii::app()->baseUrl`

```
deleteButtonImageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'mymodule/assets/img/admin/thePicture.png',
```

or

```
deleteButtonImageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/mymodule/assets/img/admin/thePicture.png',
```

Comment: none of those work....this is freakin weird..i swear there's no typo error at all